# jQuery waypoint not working at all

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im learning jQuery and one of the first things that i was trying to learn was to trigger an event when i reach certain point of the page using the Waypoint plugin.

For some reason everything ive tried its not working for me.  So i decided to go to the most basics but still dont get  it to work

Here is what im doing.

HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="div1">1</div>
        <div class="div2">2</div>
        <div class="div3">3</div>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/test.js"</script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.div1 {
    height: 2000px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}

.div2 {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.div3 {
    height: 2000px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

and the JS file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.div2').waypoint(function () {
    alert('Waypoint here');    
    });
});
```

Im suppose to get a popup when i reach div2 but i dont, also i changed alert for console.log to see any messages on the console but i dont get a single message.  I dont know what i could be doing wrong.

Note .. If i try to replicate this same code on a snippet, it works but i cant make it work locally.   Can someone please shed some light on what can i be doing wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.div2').waypoint(function () {
    alert('Waypoint here');    
    });
});
```

```css
.div1 {
    height: 2000px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}

.div2 {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.div3 {
    height: 2000px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
        <div class="div1">1</div>
        <div class="div2">2</div>
        <div class="div3">3</div>
        
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/3.1.1/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have check you code: You have missed `>` sign in script tag.

```
 <script src="js/test.js"</script>
```

Replace to

```
<script src="js/test.js"></script>
```

Check it now. Does it solve your local issue?

Comment: Thank you, this works.  Now i have to figure out why is it not working on my main page. Ill go back and check the code on the other side.  Thank you again